# Retrieve count of plays by date via Vimeo API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

Does anyone know how to retrieve the count of plays (loads, finishes, etc) in a specific time range in Vimeo API, please?

It might seem simple/stupid - and forgive me, I'm still learning - but I've only found the total count by video. I need the total plays by month/year in a report.

This information is available in the web stats, however (https://vimeo.com/stats/date). I couldn't make it via API, though.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so we can better assist you. Please click on edit and paste your code into the question. Then select the code and format it.

Comment: The simple request "GET https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos" brings me the data of all videos.
What really matters to me, however, is the total count of plays by date, not video. And I haven't found a way of making a correct request to get it.

Comment: Any ideas, @Mozahler, please?